# Conversion of a DEM model from Baltic Height system 1977 to EGM96

Tags: dem, convert

I have a raster DEM model (geotiff) with horizontal coordinate system EPSG:4326 and vertical heights regarding the Baltic Heigts system 1977 https://epsg.io/5705

I'm trying to convert it into EGM96 heights, but unsuccessfully.

For example, I tried the next GDAL command:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326+5705 -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm96_15.gtx" input_file.tif output_file.tif
```

as well as

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326+5705 -t_srs EPSG:4326+5773 input_file.tif output_file.tif
```

but in both cases the created file is identical to the input file (exactly same pixel values).

What I'm doing wrong? Do I lack some additional information (files?) to do such conversion?